# Which set of training weeks should I choose according to the book “Daniels' Running Formula”

Tags: running-training-plan

According to the "Daniels' Running Formula" book there is a possibility to create training plan for different preparation time (1-24 weeks).

[image: Daniels mesophases]

E.g. you have 6 weeks before the running event you want to participate. So according to the book you should pick 3 weeks from *Phase I "Early Season Running" (Foundation)* and 3 weeks from *Phase IV "Tapering and Peaking" (Final Quality)*. Each phase has 6 weeks and you should pick only three of them.

So the question is **which weeks should I choose in each phase?**

```
   Phase I: No.1-3;     Phase IV: No.1-3;
OR Phase I: No.1-3;     Phase IV: No.4-6;
OR Phase I: No.1, 3, 5; Phase IV: No.1, 3, 5;
OR ...?
```

I could not find any reference which weeks to choose. Also there are some weeks in Phase IV that does not have Competition session, so those weeks should not be the last ones. And it gets even more complicated when we have some but not all weeks from *Phase II "Speed, Strength, and Running Economy training" (Early quality)* and *Phase III "High intensity training" (Transition quality)*.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find in his 2nd edition book, page 69, you should do phase I (weeks 1,2,3); and phase IV (weeks 4,5,6). If you have a solid base and find phase 1 a bit too easy, then go to phase 2. The bottom two lines, just before Figure 4.2, says:

> If a runner has six weeks available before his or her last race, allocate three weeks of phase I training (priority weeks 1,2,3) and three weeks of phase IV training (priority weeks 4,5,6).

Jack Daniels referred to phase I as a "Foundation and injury prevention" phase. Table 4.1 on page 82 describes phase I as "easy runs and strides".

His priorities for following the training phases are sequential, if you have the time for all four phases. But, if you have already been doing lots of easy runs with some strides, then you won't likely get hurt going into phase II.

Comment: Please add quotation (*From what I could find*) so I could understand why you suggest this choise of weeks. And understand the way to choose weeks when preparation has different time more than 6 weeks or less than 6 weeks.

Comment: *"If you have a solid base and find phase 1 a bit too easy, then go to phase 2"* that's a good point. Don't know whether it is taken from the book or it is yours recommendation

Comment: Found that place in the book *"If a runner has six weeks available before his or her last race..."*, there is nothing about *phase I training (priority weeks 1,2,3)*. It is told that you have 6 week, so you pick as many weeks from the phase as there are weeks with this numbers in the choosing weeks picture, e.g. 4, 5, 6 numbers are in Phase VI, but there is also number 17

Answer (score 0):

Up until now, I have not found any advices from the book like *"If you can do only N-weeks from Phase-G, choose weeks number X, Y, Z"* or *"..., choose weeks which you find the best suits your needs"*

But there is a recomendation when a phase has only one week to be choosen (e.g. you have 7 weeks before start, so there is only 1 week should be choosen from Phase II). J.Danniels recomendation is (not literally, cause I have russian edition):

> If you feel/suppose that there is no profit in changing your plan just for one week of another phase, you can add this week from another phase which already has several weeks, e.g. add one more Foundation training week. And it would be 4 weeks from Phase I, and 3 weeks from Phase IV.

So I suppose that he leaves decidion to us also in case of choosing certain weeks for a phase. Choosing according to our previous researches and observation of our reaction to different kinds of physical exercises.